# How to get the URL generated from Scripts.Render(“~/bundles/someScript”)?

Tags: asp.net

When I do `Scripts.Render(“~/bundles/someScript”)`, it may be translated into something like

```
<script src="/someURL/bundles/someScript?v=asdY9xOxSVHQfe4hgu-iqLwv6wr6rbpT3YvcuODIqQ1"></script>
```

My question is, how can I get the value that is generated this value `/someURL/bundles/someScript?v=asdY9xOxSVHQfe4hgu-iqLwv6wr6rbpT3YvcuODIqQ1` and store it into some variable ?

Comment: in the code file???

Comment: in the aspx file.

Comment: Scripts.Render returns IHtmlString , have you tried to store this in a variable?

Comment: Never mind, I found out already, I can use `<%: Scripts.Url("~/bundles/someScript") %>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to find out the solution, is to use `<%: Scripts.Url("~/bundles/someScript") %>`. This will produce the URL generated by `Scripts.Render` method.